# MVC3 not calling controller in external assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create an area in a separate assembly. My route appears correct, according to RouteDebugger, but I am getting a “The controller for path {0} was not found or does not implement IController.” error.

I verified that the controller is registered in my container, but under a different namespace which I am specifying in my route.

Route registration:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "EventCalendar", 
        "EventCalendar/{action}/{id}", 
        new { controller = "EventCalendar", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
        new[] { "MyAssembly.MyName.Controllers", " MyAssembly.MyName" }
    );
```

Controller:

```
namespace MyAssembly.MyName.Controllers
{
    public class EventCalendarController : Controller
    {
        public PartialViewResult Index()
        {
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/EventCalendar/Index.cshtml",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<object>(this.ViewData.Model)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I am specifying both the namespace of the controller and the parent namespace in the route. Examples I have looked at are not clear as to which one is required. OrchardCMS uses the parent namespace. 
Am I registering the route correctly?

As long as the controller is in my container, and the namespace matches, it should resolve and be invoked right? The controllers in the main assembly work fine.

Comment: is the separate assembly referenced?

Comment: It's not referenced. I use StructureMap to scan it for instances of IController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use Dependency Injection for doing that. I'm working on a project with a similar approach (some Controllers in separated assemblies) and we're using Unity to inject the controllers to the MVC project. Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2) URL could be helpful

Also please ensure that the corresponding dll is on the bin folder of your MVC project, so the  type can be resolved

Comment: I am using DI and I have verified that the controller is in the container.

Comment: is the separate assembly on the bin folder of your MVC project?

Comment: It gets copied into a sub-folder in the bin foldr. From there, it is scanned and registered in my StructureMap container.

Comment: That actually turned out to be the issue. I copied the dll into the bin folder instead of a subfolder and it worked. It seems that just registering the dll and the controller is not enough.

Comment: Nope, I had the same problem and find out that the dll file needs to be exactly on that folder. The good thing it that it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually be surprised if this was it, but the Namespace array MapRoute expects is of type string, not object.

```
new string[] { "MyAssembly.MyName.Controllers", " MyAssembly.MyName" }
```